# Is it possible to attach a Ninja UI autocomplete to an existing input element?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I wanted to try the autocomplete that comes with [Ninja UI](http://ninjaui.com) instead of the one that comes with [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com) but could not work out from the solitary example how to attach it to an existing input element, e.g.

```
$.ninja.autocomplete(attachMeTo = $("#existing_input"), other options);
```

Does this functionality exist in Ninja UI, and if so, what is the syntax?

Comment: check docs http://ninjaui.com/#autocomplete

Comment: @sushanthreddy Given that I referred to the solitary example on the site, you can assume that I also saw the notes to the left. Is your answer "Obviously no, since the docs make no mention of it", or "Obviously yes, since what you are calling 'attachMeTo' is actually ..."?

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are getting at, it appears to be a bit confusing. I found this however:

Create an element to place it in:

```
<p id="autocompleteSamples"></p>
```

Deploy the script as per their example and your choice of options or whatever:

```
$autocompleteSample = $.ninja.autocomplete({
  placeholder: 'United States Cities'
}).values(function (event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      country: 'US',
      featureClass: 'P',
      fuzzy: 0,
      maxRows: 10,
      q: event.query
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $autocompleteSample.list({
        values: $.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
          return {
            html: item.name + ', ' + item.adminName1,
            value: item.name + ', ' + item.adminCode1
          };
        }),
        query: event.query
      });
    },
    error: function (request, status, message) {
      $.error(message);
    }
  });
}),
```

append the newly made NinjaUI autocomplete to the element you created earlier

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#autocompleteSamples').append($autocompleteSample);
});
```

I found this by digging through their scripts.js file http://ninjaui.com/script.js